# How to separate all faces

Tags: faces

I have a default torus

In edit mode i have duplicate 2 times and select all and Press P key i get 3 option by loose parts and when i click get 3 torus separate in outliner.

But when i select the single torus in edit mode select all the faces and hit P key and select loose parts and nothing happens. Here im not getting all the faces separate like the torus separated above.

How can i get separate loose faces. Is there any addon or how can i get all 576 faces separate.

[image]

Comment: your single torus faces are not separated but connected. Thus they are not "loose parts". It seems you wish a way to get separate faces from an object made of connected faces... right? Your multi torus example doesn't help me to understand... tried selecting all faces then ctrl-e > edge split?

Comment: @m.ardito how to separate all the faces attach to the torus. Like we separate if we have multiple cube array and then if we need to loose we separate how to separate the torus face. I need all the 576 faces to be separate in outliner. so that i link and add mesh and then join

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an edge split modifier, set the angle to 0 and apply the modifier. Then you can select all the faces in edit mode and P separate by loose parts.

Answer (score 9):

You can avoid the modifier step: as said above in comments,

- in edit mode, select all faces
- then use <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> to split all edges

[image]

- now all faces are unconnected (note the vertices/edges count increased)
- then select all and press <kbd>P</kbd> to split by "loose parts"

[image]

- now you have an indipendent object for each face

[image]

Comment: Thats cool both the answer much satisfied but i have to give any 1 answer tick mark. Thanks for the reply.